# unable to ssh to ec2 inside vpc's public subnet

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

My load balanced, auto scaling Elastic Beanstalk environment uses a VPC with public and private subnets in two AZs.

- The ELB and EC2s are in the same public subnets.
- The EC2s have been given a public IP.
- The EC2s are in a security group with an inbound rule opening port 22 to **0.0.0.0/0** (I've also tried with my IP)
- The EC2s are associated with the key pair I'm using (it's working for other EC2s outside this VPC).
- The EC2s are healthy.

But...

```
ssh -i "~/.ssh/my.pem" ec2-user@ec2-my-instance-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

... results in "Operation timed out".

What obvious thing am I missing?

---

Edit: Inbound rules on the public subnet's ACL:

[image]

Inbound rules on EC2's SG:

[image]

Public subnet details:

```
Subnet ID: subnet-3cf38775 | Public subnet 2
Availability Zone: eu-west-1b
IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.2.0/24

Route Table:
10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> nat-01b4b81a02e336d3c
```

Comment: Public subnets must use igw as default gateway and not nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the subnet that instance is in have a route to `0.0.0.0/0` to the internet gateway attached to the VPC?

Also does the security group have `0.0.0.0/0` all or just tcp on the egress?

Comment: Hi - I've added screenshots of ACL and SG inbound rules. Do they answer your questions? I'm a bit confused by the ACL, TBH - why's it got ALLOW and DENY for both?

Comment: ok but what about the egress for SG and NACL?

Comment: Outbound rules are identical for the ACL. There's only one outbound rule for the EC2's SG, allow all traffic / all protocols / all ports on 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: ok what about the route table for the subnet?

Comment: Subnet ID: subnet-3cf38775 | Public subnet 2
Availability Zone: eu-west-1b
IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.2.0/24

Route Table:
10.0.0.0/16 -> local
0.0.0.0/0 -> nat-01b4b81a02e336d3c`

Comment: Flippin' line breaks. Added to OP.

Comment: the route table is your issue.. you need to route public subnets to the internet gateway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66539/discussion-between-wintermute-and-mike).

Answer (score 0):

Adding summary here for clarity, although @Mike kindly talked me through to the correct point above. I have a two public (and two private) subnets (in two AZ's), and the route table attached to the public subnet containing my unreachable EC2 was not routing traffic to the internet gateway. I changed the route table on that subnet to use the same route table as the other public subnet and now everything is just dandy.